# Line not appearing on plot when using lines() in R

Tags: r, regression, line

I'm doing a polynomial regression and I want to plot it.

My code is the following:

#### to create polynomial regression to degree 1

```
mreg6=lm(user_Score~poly(year_of_Release,1))
```

#### to create plot

```
plot(year_of_Release~user_Score, col='gray')
```

#### to create line

```
lines(sort(year_of_Release),predict(mreg6)[order(year_of_Release)],col='red')
```

#### to create legend

```
legend('topright',lty=1:2,col=c('red'),c('degree 1'))
```

When I run the code, there is no error but the line does not appear on graph.
Do any of you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It might help to have example data to reproduce this problem (e.g., using `dput()`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The formula interface `plot(year_of_Release ~ user_Score, col='gray')` in `plot` treats the first variable as `y` and the second as `x`, so `year_of_Release` is plotted on the y-axis even though it's the `x` variable in the regression. If you look at your graph, you'll likely see the variables are not on the axes you expected. Either reverse the order or change to `plot(year_of_Release, user_Score)`

Comment: To complete the explanation, `lines` is indeed plotting a line, but since the variables are on the correct axes and have different ranges, the location where the line is "plotted" is not within the range of the x and y limits of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer: I was putting ~ instead of , in plot() so it was giving me another regression.

Comment: It wasn't giving you a regression, it was plotting the columns in reverse order (since the formula interface is `y ~ x`, as compare with `x, y`). See the second comment below your question for details.